# ContentEditable Div blur event

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am using a content editable div as an input control but it does not send information to the server like a textarea or input element does so I've used the blur event to transfer the information from the div to a hidden field and then sending the value of the hidden field to the server.

This works intermittently, my question is.  Is there a better way?  Is there some way to send the value of innerHTML or innerTEXT of the mentioned div element or should I be using a different event (Maybe focus on the button).  Not sure.

Comment: Right... That's the only way! `:(` Try using `keyup`.

Comment: I didn't think of key up. I'll give it a try.  Thank you.

Comment: Keyup works a lot better.  Thank you.  Problem was that the control allows for image posting and when posting an image the keyup event isn't triggered.  So I used the blur event on the div as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect a click outside of the div but it has the same affect as onblur and onblur is much better to implement.

Comment: Things like this often work, but not in my case with slatejs